# Laravel database implode function

Tags: php, laravel

I have inserted values into database for multiple selection like this somevalue1, somevalue2, somevalue3 in Laravel using implode function.

Controller.php

```
          $project_name=$request->project_name;
          $project_id=$request->project_id;
          $client_id=$request->client_id;
          $project_status=$request->project_status;
          $approver = implode(",",Input::get(array('approver')));
```

I want value in separately not like somevalue1, somevalue2. How can I solved this?

Comment: you dont want comma??

Comment: No idea what your question is. You use implode, but you don't want to use implode? What is the actual problem. What do you have, vs what do you want? Show examples and more, relevant code.

Comment: No when inserting it is inserted with comma , when i'm fetching the whole value is coming in a single string, i want it in separate string without comma

Comment: Use `explode` on the string you get back from the DB then?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `json_encode` during saving to database.

```
$save_approver = json_encode($request->approver);
```

and `json_decode` when retrieving from database.

```
$get_approver = json_decode($your_variable, TRUE);
foreach($get_approver as $value){
    // operations
}
```